# How is continuation executed after await in WinForms/WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, asynchronous, async-await

I am trying to gracefully discard long running operations which are in the essence a sequence of downloading data and updating the UI.

For example user selects an item and its details start being loaded from the server. But then he changes his mind and selects another item. The previous operation is cancelled, and the process starts again. Yet there is a possibility that data is already received and continuation is posted to the message loop for execution. The question is whether it is possible with `async/await`.

There is a [blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/10/05/how-do-i-cancel-non-cancelable-async-operations/) by Stephen Toub where he offers this extension:

```
public static async Task<T> WithCancellation<T>( 
    this Task<T> task, CancellationToken cancellationToken) 
{ 
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>(); 
    using(cancellationToken.Register( 
                s => ((TaskCompletionSource<bool>)s).TrySetResult(true), tcs)) 
        if (task != await Task.WhenAny(task, tcs.Task)) 
            throw new OperationCanceledException(cancellationToken); 
    return await task; 
}
```

In return statement `return await task` task is already completed.
If I am awaiting a task in UI thread:

```
var result = await task.WithCancellation(token);
...continuation...
```

The `return await task;` is executed in UI thread.

**But does `continuation` run synchronously with continuation of awaited async method or is posted separately to the message loop?**

Synchronous execution allows to avoid the situation when cancellation (user selects another item) occurs later than continuation appears in message queue. If this is not the case, then I have to check additionally:

```
var result = await task.WithCancellation(token);
token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
...continuation...
```

Comment: The continuation is posted back to the message loop. So yes, there is a short window of time where the token could be cancelled

Answer (score 0):

Continuation will run asynchronously till the first await inside your task, then it will return to the task execution.